# How can I compile a python lib with a specific version of python?

Tags: gcc, python-3.x

I'm trying to build [cwiid](https://github.com/abstrakraft/cwiid) with **python 3.2** bindings to make use of the **Wiimote** in **Blender 2.63**. My OS is ubuntu 12.04.
I set up **virtualenv** to provide the correct python version for the build.
Here is what I did so far (bash-shell record):

```
# Set up virtualenv with python3.2
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools  
sudo easy_install virtualenv  
virtualenv -p python3.2 --no-site-packages ~/env/cwiid_for_blender  
# to activate, type this:  
source ~/env/cwiid_for_blender/bin/activate  
python --version # returns "Python 3.2.3"  

# Build cwiid
# prerequisites  
sudo apt-get install bison bluez libbluetooth3 libbluetooth-dev libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-dev  
# download and compile sources of cwiid  
mkdir -p ~/Downloads/cwiid  
cd ~/Downloads/cwiid  
git clone https://github.com/abstrakraft/cwiid.git  
cd cwiid  
source ~/env/cwiid_for_blender/bin/activate  
aclocal  
autoconf  
./configure  
make
```

This fails because [cwiid](https://github.com/abstrakraft/cwiid) is normally built against python 2.7. In the configure script there is this line:

```
PYTHON_VERSION=`$PYTHON -c 'import sys; print sys.version[:3]'`
```

After changing it to the 3.2 syntax like this:

```
PYTHON_VERSION=`$PYTHON -c 'import sys; print( sys.version[:3] )'`
```

The make script starts to compile but fails when hitting the following line:

```
gcc -L../libcwiid -rdynamic -o wminput main.o conf.o c_plugin.o uinput.o action_enum.o util.o py_plugin.o parser.o lexer.o -lcwiid -lbluetooth -ldl -lpthread -lpython3.2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.2
```

Interestingly the script is able to continue to the next error if I append `mu` to the line:

```
gcc -L../libcwiid -rdynamic -o wminput main.o conf.o c_plugin.o uinput.o action_enum.o util.o py_plugin.o parser.o lexer.o -lcwiid -lbluetooth -ldl -lpthread -lpython3.2mu
```

I don't understand where gcc searches for the 3.2 libraries and how I can specify that. Specifically I don't understand if the `configure` script has to be fixed or if I have to change my enviroment to fix this issue.
Suggestions by others so far:

- Make a symbolic link from `python3.2->python3.2mu`. (But where? Tried several locations, none worked)
- Add file with directories to look up in `/etd/ld.so.conf.d/`

So, **how does gcc find the python3.2 libraries it needs to build libcwiid?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while it became clear that the `configure` script was not correctly interpreting the python version. This was showed up in the Makefiles as they contained direct links to version 2.7. After correcting the make files the compilation went on to the real problems. So now, I'm trying to port the real code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you have installed the Python dev libraries.

```
sudo apt-get install python3.2-dev
```

Secondly, I don't understand why it would need Python libraries to build it in the first place. libcwiid doesn't seem to contain any Python or include the Python library. I suggest you remove the -lpython3.2 and see what happens. The Python module that wraps libcwiid of course needs Python, but that's another issue.

Also note that cwiid evidently doesn't support Python 3. But that is only an issue if you want the cwiid Python module, ie if you want to use it from Python 3. The error you have is while compiling libcwiid, though, which is a C-library.

Comment: I'll try that. If I understand you correctly that means there is a flaw in the `configure` script which I will try to correct.

Comment: @tuner: What I'm saying is that first of all, make sure that libpython3.2 is installed, and secondly that I don't think the configure script needs to include libpython at all. If this is a "flaw" or not is up to you to decide. You not installing python3.2-dev is most definitively not a flaw in the configure script.

Comment: libpython3.2 is (and was) installed. It seems to be installed with m (malloc) and u (unicode) enabled. libcwiid does need the python libs and complains about undefined references in py_plugin.c. Maybe the flags for the cwiid compile need the m and u flags as well?

Comment: @tuner: Aha, the wminput has Python bindings. Do you need wminput? Otherwise you might be able to skip it. I don't know how blender uses cwiid. It is looking like a complete port to Python 3 is needed, though.

Comment: Yes I do. :-) Blender is not using cwiid - I want to use it with Blender. If I have to port the thing to Python 3 so be it. Fixing the code is apparently easier for me than to fix my enviroment. So I still wonder why some libraries are found with the `-lpython3.2mu` flag and if it matters if the libraries are compiled with the m and u flags.

Comment: @tuner: For that you should probably ask a GCC question. Good luck with the port!